# TypeError - sanityClient is not a function

Tags: node.js, next.js, require, netlify, sanity

```
const sanityClient = require('@sanity/client')
const client = sanityClient({
projectId: 'PROJECT_ID',
dataset: 'production',
token: process.env.TOKEN
})
```

I'm passing parameters in netlify functions file to sanityClient. I get error sanityClient is not a function. I am using sanity and netlify with Next.js. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a research after I posted this question.Require is not working on netlify functions therefore add this to netlify.toml

```
[functions]
  node_bundler = "esbuild"
```

This will allow to import modules to netlify function files.
Then import:

```
import sanityClient from "@sanity/client";
const client = sanityClient({
projectId: 'PROJECT_ID',
dataset: 'production', 
token: SANITY_TOKEN
})
```